# Rolling function from pandas to polars

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I have this function in pandas:

```py
def rolling_pd(
    dataf: pd.DataFrame,
    groupby_cols: Union[str, list],
    column: str,
    function: str = "mean",
    rolling_periods: int = 1,
    shift_periods: int = 1,
    *args,
    **kwargs,
) -> pd.Series:
    return dataf.groupby(groupby_cols)[column].transform(
        lambda d: (
            d.shift(shift_periods)
            .rolling(rolling_periods, min_periods=1)
            .agg(function, *args, **kwargs)
        )
    )
```

I want to do the same thing with polars, haven't maanged since I don't see a rolling method, can you help me do this translation?

Comment: could you make a reproducible example please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us consider the following data.

```py
import polars as pl
    
df = pl.DataFrame({
   "group": ["a"] * 4 + ["b"] * 4,
   "value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
})
```

```
>>> df

shape: (8, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ 1     │
│ a     ┆ 2     │
│ a     ┆ 3     │
│ a     ┆ 4     │
│ b     ┆ 5     │
│ b     ┆ 6     │
│ b     ┆ 7     │
│ b     ┆ 8     │
└───────┴───────┘
```

---

For a fixed aggregation function, one could use the corresponding `pl.Expr.rolling_*` function. As an example (with `rolling_periods = 2` and `shift_periods = 1`), consider [`pl.Expr.rolling_mean`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling_mean.html):

```
(
    df_pl
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("value").shift(1).rolling_mean(window_size=2, min_periods=1).over("group")
    )
)
```

**Output.**

```
shape: (8, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ f64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ null  │
│ a     ┆ 1.0   │
│ a     ┆ 1.5   │
│ a     ┆ 2.5   │
│ b     ┆ null  │
│ b     ┆ 5.0   │
│ b     ┆ 5.5   │
│ b     ┆ 6.5   │
└───────┴───────┘
```

---

However, this gets more complex when we want to apply an arbitrary aggregation function based on the corresponding name as in the pandas
example provided in the question.

In this case, we can use [`pl.Expr.rolling`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling.html#polars.Expr.rolling). Unfortunately, `rolling` doesn't infer an index column and we have to create it manually.

Moreover, we can rely on Python's built-in [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to obtain the aggregation function in the `pl.Expr` namespace by name.

```
def rolling_pl(
    data: pl.DataFrame,
    groupby_cols: Union[str, list],
    column: str,
    function: str = "mean",
    rolling_periods: int = 1,
    shift_periods: int = 1,
    *args,
    **kwargs,
) -> pd.Series:
    return (
        data
        .with_columns(pl.int_range(0,pl.count()).cast(pl.Int64).alias('index'))
        .rolling(
            index_column="index",
            period=f"{rolling_periods}i",
            closed="both",
            by=groupby_cols
        )
        .agg(
            getattr(pl.col(column).shift(shift_periods), function)(*args, **kwargs)
        )
        .drop("index")
    )
```